# dual boot MSI GS-60 with ubuntu and windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, msi

Hi I have bought a notebook MSI GS60-6QE16H11 Ghost 15,6" 4K-UHD / Intel Core i7-6700HQ / 16GB / Hybrid 1128GB / GTX 970M / Win 10. And I want to have dual boot with ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 but I can not achieve it. I have installed windows in the SSD hard disk, and ubuntu 15.10 in the HDD. The WI-FI does not work in the ubuntu. When I install NVIDIA drivers or bumblebee then ubuntu does not work,(it shows black screen or purple). I have searched in forums but non of the "solved" issues works. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm sure if you google each individual driver, you'd find a compatible driver. I know it's not the answer you want, but it's the only one that may actually work. The ubuntu software repository doesn't always provide the latest drivers for all known hardware, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only get a black screen after installing nvidia proprietary driver try this:

- when in grub, select your default boot option (should be named Ubuntu) and press "e"
- search for a line with "quiet splash"
- delete "quiet" and "splash" and instead add "intel.idle_max.cstate=1"
- press "F10"
- enjoy a working Ubuntu or post what error you got

Also see this thread: [Getting Ubuntu working properly on MSI GE62 6QF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692673/getting-ubuntu-working-properly-on-msi-ge62-6qf[/url])