# Can't install Ubuntu to Dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I bought a new computer and have been trying to install ubuntu 16.04 onto it alongside windows 10.

I have used unetbootin to create a bootable drive and followed this guide to installing ubuntu on my computer. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html I have also turned off Fast Start Up in Windows.

When I boot off of the USB and select either "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" After a few minutes of loading the splash screen freezes. I thought it might be processing so I let it sit for 8 hours and it was still stuck.

After a few tries I turned off the splash screen and tried again. After running for a little bit I get the following error message:`BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s` and it just repeats about every 20 seconds. I've tried a few times and this message happens everytime but at different points during the boot so I can't pinpoint it to exactly one point during the boot up.

After looking into this error a bit I've been told it may be a linux kernel issue with my hardware. To test this I tried installing Ubunutu 14.04 but still got the same error, then I tried 12.04 and I was able to get it to start with "Try Ubuntu". From here the aspect ratio was horribly off but I figured I'd be able to fix this after install so I tried to install from 12.04 but the installation failed during the install for "Unknown Reasons" after I selected the partition.

My Computer Specs are as Follows:

My computer is an "AORUS X5S V5-SL1":
 - 16G Ram DDR4
 - i7-6700HQ
 - 512GB PCIe NVMe SSD + 1TB 7200RPM Hard Drive (trying to install on the SSD)
 - NVIDIA® GeForce GTX 980M (8.0GB) GDDR5 (Maxwell) w/ Optimus™ Technology
 - UEFI Mother Board
 - 64 Bit

If anyone can help please let me know, I've never had issues installing Ubuntu on a computer before and am out of ideas.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/692673/getting-ubuntu-working-properly-on-msi-ge62-6qf  seems pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

If your problems are solved, look at the following link for additional ideas of what to try:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)